# XmlSerializer: remove unnecessary xsi and xsd namespaces

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

Is there a way to configure the XmlSerializer so that it doesn't write default namespaces in the root element?

What I get is this:

```
<?xml ...>
<rootelement xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns:xsd="...">
</rootelement>
```

and I want to remove both xmlns declarations.

**Duplicate of**: [How to serialize an object to XML without getting xmlns=”…”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258960)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Since Dave asked for me to repeat my answer to [Omitting all xsi and xsd namespaces when serializing an object in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11129732/1470649), I have updated this post and repeated my answer here from the afore-mentioned link. The example used in this answer is the same example used for the other question. What follows is copied, verbatim.

---

After reading Microsoft's documentation and several solutions online, I have discovered the solution to this problem. It works with both the built-in `XmlSerializer` and custom XML serialization via `IXmlSerialiazble`.

To whit, I'll use the same `MyTypeWithNamespaces` XML sample that's been used in the answers to this question so far.

```cs
[XmlRoot("MyTypeWithNamespaces", Namespace="urn:Abracadabra", IsNullable=false)]
public class MyTypeWithNamespaces
{
    // As noted below, per Microsoft's documentation, if the class exposes a public
    // member of type XmlSerializerNamespaces decorated with the 
    // XmlNamespacesDeclarationAttribute, then the XmlSerializer will utilize those
    // namespaces during serialization.
    public MyTypeWithNamespaces( )
    {
        this._namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new XmlQualifiedName[] {
            // Don't do this!! Microsoft's documentation explicitly says it's not supported.
            // It doesn't throw any exceptions, but in my testing, it didn't always work.

            // new XmlQualifiedName(string.Empty, string.Empty),  // And don't do this:
            // new XmlQualifiedName("", "")

            // DO THIS:
            new XmlQualifiedName(string.Empty, "urn:Abracadabra") // Default Namespace
            // Add any other namespaces, with prefixes, here.
        });
    }

    // If you have other constructors, make sure to call the default constructor.
    public MyTypeWithNamespaces(string label, int epoch) : this( )
    {
        this._label = label;
        this._epoch = epoch;
    }

    // An element with a declared namespace different than the namespace
    // of the enclosing type.
    [XmlElement(Namespace="urn:Whoohoo")]
    public string Label
    {
        get { return this._label; }
        set { this._label = value; }
    }
    private string _label;

    // An element whose tag will be the same name as the property name.
    // Also, this element will inherit the namespace of the enclosing type.
    public int Epoch
    {
        get { return this._epoch; }
        set { this._epoch = value; }
    }
    private int _epoch;

    // Per Microsoft's documentation, you can add some public member that
    // returns a XmlSerializerNamespaces object. They use a public field,
    // but that's sloppy. So I'll use a private backed-field with a public
    // getter property. Also, per the documentation, for this to work with
    // the XmlSerializer, decorate it with the XmlNamespaceDeclarations
    // attribute.
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces Namespaces
    {
        get { return this._namespaces; }
    }
    private XmlSerializerNamespaces _namespaces;
}
```

That's all to this class. Now, some objected to having an `XmlSerializerNamespaces` object somewhere within their classes; but as you can see, I neatly tucked it away in the default constructor and exposed a public property to return the namespaces.

Now, when it comes time to serialize the class, you would use the following code:

```cs
MyTypeWithNamespaces myType = new MyTypeWithNamespaces("myLabel", 42);

/******
   OK, I just figured I could do this to make the code shorter, so I commented out the
   below and replaced it with what follows:

// You have to use this constructor in order for the root element to have the right namespaces.
// If you need to do custom serialization of inner objects, you can use a shortened constructor.
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTypeWithNamespaces), new XmlAttributeOverrides(),
    new Type[]{}, new XmlRootAttribute("MyTypeWithNamespaces"), "urn:Abracadabra");

******/

/*****
  Per @dbc, since MyTypeWithNamespaces has a XmlRootAttribute decorating the class,
  You may be able to get away with NOT using this .ctor and use the simple
  XmlSerializer(Type) .ctor.
  Also, be careful not to use serializer creation in loops, as it could lead
  to extensive memory issues due to how serializers are cached (or not...).
  See @dbc's comment and link to SO Q&A for more details.

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTypeWithNamespaces),
    new XmlRootAttribute("MyTypeWithNamespaces") { Namespace="urn:Abracadabra" });
****/
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTypeWithNamespaces));

// I'll use a MemoryStream as my backing store.
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

// This is extra! If you want to change the settings for the XmlSerializer, you have to create
// a separate XmlWriterSettings object and use the XmlTextWriter.Create(...) factory method.
// So, in this case, I want to omit the XML declaration.
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
xws.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; // This is probably the default
// You could use the XmlWriterSetting to set indenting and new line options, but the
// XmlTextWriter class has a much easier method to accomplish that.

// The factory method returns a XmlWriter, not a XmlTextWriter, so cast it.
XmlTextWriter xtw = (XmlTextWriter)XmlTextWriter.Create(ms, xws);
// Then we can set our indenting options (this is, of course, optional).
xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

// Now serialize our object.
xs.Serialize(xtw, myType, myType.Namespaces);
```

Once you have done this, you should get the following output:

```
<MyTypeWithNamespaces>
    <Label xmlns="urn:Whoohoo">myLabel</Label>
    <Epoch>42</Epoch>
</MyTypeWithNamespaces>
```

I have successfully used this method in a recent project with a deep hierachy of classes that are serialized to XML for web service calls. Microsoft's documentation is not very clear about what to do with the publicly accesible `XmlSerializerNamespaces` member once you've created it, and so many think it's useless. But by following their documentation and using it in the manner shown above, you can customize how the XmlSerializer generates XML for your classes without resorting to unsupported behavior or "rolling your own" serialization by implementing `IXmlSerializable`.

It is my hope that this answer will put to rest, once and for all, how to get rid of the standard `xsi` and `xsd` namespaces generated by the `XmlSerializer`.

UPDATE: I just want to make sure I answered the OP's question about removing all namespaces. My code above will work for this; let me show you how. Now, in the example above, you really can't get rid of all namespaces (because there are two namespaces in use). Somewhere in your XML document, you're going to need to have something like `xmlns="urn:Abracadabra" xmlns:w="urn:Whoohoo`. If the class in the example is part of a larger document, then somewhere above a namespace must be declared for either one of (or both) `Abracadbra` and `Whoohoo`. If not, then the element in one or both of the namespaces must be decorated with a prefix of some sort (you can't have two default namespaces, right?). So, for this example, `Abracadabra` is the default namespace. I could inside my `MyTypeWithNamespaces` class add a namespace prefix for the `Whoohoo` namespace like so:

```cs
public MyTypeWithNamespaces
{
    this._namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new XmlQualifiedName[] {
        new XmlQualifiedName(string.Empty, "urn:Abracadabra"), // Default Namespace
        new XmlQualifiedName("w", "urn:Whoohoo")
    });
}
```

Now, in my class definition, I indicated that the `<Label/>` element is in the namespace `"urn:Whoohoo"`, so I don't need to do anything further. When I now serialize the class using my above serialization code unchanged, this is the output:

```
<MyTypeWithNamespaces xmlns:w="urn:Whoohoo">
    <w:Label>myLabel</w:Label>
    <Epoch>42</Epoch>
</MyTypeWithNamespaces>
```

Because `<Label>` is in a different namespace from the rest of the document, it must, in someway, be "decorated" with a namespace. Notice that there are still no `xsi` and `xsd` namespaces.

---

This ends my answer to the other question. But I wanted to make sure I answered the OP's question about using no namespaces, as I feel I didn't really address it yet. Assume that `<Label>` is part of the same namespace as the rest of the document, in this case `urn:Abracadabra`:

```
<MyTypeWithNamespaces>
    <Label>myLabel<Label>
    <Epoch>42</Epoch>
</MyTypeWithNamespaces>
```

Your constructor would look as it would in my very first code example, along with the public property to retrieve the default namespace:

```cs
// As noted below, per Microsoft's documentation, if the class exposes a public
// member of type XmlSerializerNamespaces decorated with the 
// XmlNamespacesDeclarationAttribute, then the XmlSerializer will utilize those
// namespaces during serialization.
public MyTypeWithNamespaces( )
{
    this._namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new XmlQualifiedName[] {
        new XmlQualifiedName(string.Empty, "urn:Abracadabra") // Default Namespace
    });
}

[XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
public XmlSerializerNamespaces Namespaces
{
    get { return this._namespaces; }
}
private XmlSerializerNamespaces _namespaces;
```

Then, later, in your code that uses the `MyTypeWithNamespaces` object to serialize it, you would call it as I did above:

```cs
MyTypeWithNamespaces myType = new MyTypeWithNamespaces("myLabel", 42);

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTypeWithNamespaces),
    new XmlRootAttribute("MyTypeWithNamespaces") { Namespace="urn:Abracadabra" });

...

// Above, you'd setup your XmlTextWriter.

// Now serialize our object.
xs.Serialize(xtw, myType, myType.Namespaces);
```

And the `XmlSerializer` would spit back out the same XML as shown immediately above with no additional namespaces in the output:

```
<MyTypeWithNamespaces>
    <Label>myLabel<Label>
    <Epoch>42</Epoch>
</MyTypeWithNamespaces>
```

Comment: For completeness, perhaps you should include the right answer here instead of simply referring to it, and also, I'm interested to know how you conclude that it's 'unsupported behavior'.

Comment: Okay, so here it says so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Dave, I repeated my answer for you. Also, I wanted to make sure I addressed your original question about no namespaces showing up. If you have only one namespace in your XML fragment/document and you added the default namespace to a publicly available `XmlSerializerNamespaces` collection within your object with all elements belonging to that namespace, then when calling the `XmlSerializer` as I showed above, no namespaces would be output in the resulting serialzied XML. HTH.

Comment: Came here again to check this, since it's the most straightforward explanation I've found. Thanks @fourpastmidnight

Comment: I don't get it, for your final OP's answer, you are still using a namespace during serialization "urn:Abracadabra" (constructor), why is that not included in the final output.

Shouldn't the OP use : 
XmlSerializerNamespaces EmptyXmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });

Comment: It's not included in the final output because it's the default namespace--every element is assumed to belong to that namespace unless otherwise specified (e.g. as an attribute on the class being serialized to XML). Notice how XHTML declares its default namespace: `xmlns=http://....`, not `xmlns:xhtml=....`. If this were declared the second way, your pages would need to be like `<xhtml:html><xhtml:body>Your content</xhtml:body></xhtml:head>`. By specifying no namespace name, you don't need to use it in qualifying the element.

Comment: Hi @fourpastmidnight , is your solution also apply to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325097/remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-from-wcf ?

Comment: @storm_buster I'm not sure if this would work with WCF or not. WCF uses its own serialization. Now, if you are implementing your own serializer, then, yes, this solution should work just fine for you. HTH.

Comment: Hi @fourpastmidnight, any pointer no how to implement my own serializer and use it in my WCF. if you can reply in my question . really really apreciate any advise

Comment: @storm_buster I'm sorry I didn't see this response sooner. I know you can create your own WCF serializers, but I don't know how to do it off the top of my head. Hopefully you've found out how. I can try to take a look and see how that would be done in the meantime.

Comment: @storm_buster I found [this SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971743/custom-wcf-datacontractserializer) that says, yes, you can create your own WCF serializer and what you need to do to accomplish that. HTH.

Comment: This is the correct answer, although is not the most voted. The onky thing that didn't work for me was `XmlTextWriter xtw = (XmlTextWriter)XmlTextWriter.Create(ms, xws);` I had to replace by `var xtw = XmlTextWriter.Create(memStm, xws);`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez but then you do not have access to things like .Formatting. Could this problem be also addressed "properly", please?

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote this answer. `XmlTextWriter.Create` returns an (abstract?) `XmlWriter` instance. So @Preza8 is correct, you'd lose the ability to set other `XmlTextWriter`-specific properties (at least, not without down-casting it), hence, the specific cast to `XmlTextWriter`.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but why are you constructing a serializer with an `XmlRootAttribute` override that is the same as the `[XmlRoot(...)`] attribute applied to the type to be serialized?  If you do, you will have a severe memory leak unless you statically cache the serializer, see [Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897411/3744182) for why.

Comment: @dbc it may simply be an honest mistake. I'm human. It happens. More than likely, the _real_ answer is that when I made this answer, I didn't know about this condition. After all, I'm not Google, and I don't know everything. This is just example code to help illustrate how to not serialize namespace attributes when they're not necessary. I would expect any reasonable individual to read the documentation and understand the code they're copying/pasting from SO. Thanks for the comment, though! I certainly wouldn't want anyone to introduce a potential memory leak into the code.

Comment: @dbc -- I did some more research. While technically it's correct that line of code _could_ cause a memory leak, that only happens in the case of the `.ctor` in question being repeatedly used inside a loop, as apparently the serializer is not reused. Snce a new assembly is created for each serializer, the serializer cannot be GC'd out of memory. So in _that_ case, you would have a potential memory leak. However, in a one-off usage scenario, such as my example, this will not occur. Thanks for the comment and link, though, as that is _very_ important information to know under certain contexts!!

Comment: @dbc I updated the one code sample that created a serializer for the class which was decorated with the `XmlRootAttribute`. OTOH, the later example, while having the same class name, was _NOT_ decorated with an `XmlRootAttribute`, and so I kept the longer `.ctor` invocation since it would be required in that instance. In any event, one ought to know the context in which they're performing serialization and design an appropriate solution. As a one-off example, the code above is generally fine. Thanks again for your insights!

Comment: @fourpastmidnight - thanks for the response!

Answer (score 289):

```csharp
//Create our own namespaces for the output
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

//Add an empty namespace and empty value
ns.Add("", "");

//Create the serializer
XmlSerializer slz = new XmlSerializer(someType);

//Serialize the object with our own namespaces (notice the overload)
slz.Serialize(myXmlTextWriter, someObject, ns)
```

Comment: Hmmm...you guys are rebels. It explicitly says at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces(v=vs.100).aspx that you can't do that.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's "unsupported", but this does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy how would I apply your solution in my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325097/remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-from-wcf ?

Comment: This answer generates  "xmlns:d1p1" and "xmlns:q1" namespaces. What is this?

Comment: I upvoted without realizing it doesn't work. I would -1 this. `d1p1:type="MyCustomType"` `xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` is what I get when using this.

Comment: @gyozokudor: sorry you are having a problem. This post has been around a while so I just tested the code and it still works. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, this code works for really really simple serializations, without other namespace definitions. For multiple namespace definitions, the working answer is the accepted one.

Comment: Maybe it worked before, but I get the dreaded q1 in my output.  I've never seen name spaces generated on WCF [Datamember] maybe I should use it instead.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = "http://www.something.org/schema";
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person), DEFAULT_NAMESPACE);
        var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add("", DEFAULT_NAMESPACE);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var someone = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Donald",
                LastName = "Duck"
            };
            serializer.Serialize(stream, someone, namespaces);
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person xmlns="http://www.something.org/schema">
  <FirstName>Donald</FirstName>
  <LastName>Duck</LastName>
</Person>
```

If you don't want the namespace, just set DEFAULT_NAMESPACE to "".

Comment: Although this question is over 10 years old, the point of it back then was to have an XML body that did not contain any namespace declarations at all.

Comment: If I add my own answer to a question that is 10 years old it is because the accepted answer is longer to read than the Bible in its complete edition.

Comment: And the most voted answer promote an approach (empty namespace) which is not recommended.

Comment: I can't help that. I can only make the accepted answer the one I believe is the most correct.

Answer (score 7):

There is an alternative - you can provide a member of type [XmlSerializerNamespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx) in the type to be serialized. Decorate it with the [XmlNamespaceDeclarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlnamespacedeclarationsattribute.aspx) attribute.  Add the namespace prefixes and URIs to that member.  Then, any serialization that does not explicitly provide an XmlSerializerNamespaces will use the namespace prefix+URI pairs you have put into your type.

Example code, suppose this is your type:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:mycompany.2009")]
public class Person {
  [XmlAttribute] 
  public bool Known;
  [XmlElement]
  public string Name;
  [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
  public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns;
}
```

You can do this:

```
var p = new Person
  { 
      Name = "Charley",
      Known = false, 
      xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces()
  }
p.xmlns.Add("",""); // default namespace is emoty
p.xmlns.Add("c", "urn:mycompany.2009");
```

And that will mean that any serialization of that instance that does not specify its own set of prefix+URI pairs will use the "p" prefix for the "urn:mycompany.2009" namespace. It will also omit the xsi and xsd namespaces.

The difference here is that you are adding the XmlSerializerNamespaces to the type itself, rather than employing it explicitly on a call to XmlSerializer.Serialize().  This means that if an instance of your type is serialized by code you do not own (for example in a webservices stack), and that code does not explicitly provide a XmlSerializerNamespaces, that serializer will use the namespaces provided in the instance.

Comment: 1. I don't see the difference. You're still adding the default namespace to an instance of XmlSerializerNamespaces.

Comment: 2. This pollutes the classes more. My objective is not to use certain namespace, my objective is not to use namespaces at all.

Comment: I added a note about the difference between this approach and that of specifying the XmlSerializerNamespaces during serialization only.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is dirty, but it does the trick for me, just using Regex to get rid of the junk. I just don't want any xmlns thing, want to treat XML just like normal JSON. The other answers have too much ceremony.

So after serializing the object, I do:

```
string xml = "<string xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">Hello, world!</string>";
xml = Regex.Replace(x, @" xmlns:.*?"".*?""", "");
```