# Protobuf .NET serialization for inheritance classes

Tags: protobuf-net, datacontract, netdatacontractserializer

I'm trying to migrate my code serializer from NetDataContract to Protobuf.Net.

Let's consider the following class example to help the understanding:

```
[DataContract(Name "a", IsReference = true)]
class Test
{
    [DataMember(Name = "a")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "b")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To be able to use Protobuf .NET using DataContract, I'm using the following options:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.InferTagFromNameDefault = true;            
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.AutoAddProtoContractTypesOnly = false;
```

Using those options, the serialization of the example showed above works, but when adding an inheritance of it, the complexity grows. Let's improve our example with this class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "b", IsReference = true)]
class InheritanceTest : Test
{
    [DataMember(Name = "c")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Now, to be able to serialize the class "InheritanceTest" that inherits from "Test", I must add the ProtoInclude parameter (already tried to use only the KnownType but it didn't work). Class "Test" attributes should be like that:

```
[DataContract(Name "a", IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(InheritanceTest)]
[ProtoInclude(<TAG>, typeof(InheritanceTest)]
class Test { ... }
```

The complexity IMHO is when you have to fill the "TAG" with a number that is not automatically used from the members (DataMembers) auto-assigned order. In this example, if I use TAG=1 it gets error because property Id already uses it. The same with TAG=2 and property Name. So I need to put at least 3.

That's okay as this class is too simple, but what should I do when the class has several properties? And should I change the TAG whenever I add a property to it? Seems terrible for maintenance.

How can I do it in a simpler way? Am I missing something?

Considering it is automatically assigned, it should be done only once and cached. Even better, it should be done in compile time.

Additionally... why can't I use [KnownType] Attribute and the serializer auto-assigns the TAG based on the Name of the DataContract of the class type defined? Note that something similar happens with DataMember using the Name to auto-assign Order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when adding an inheritance of it, the complexity grows.

Yes, it does.

> And should I change the TAG whenever I add a property to it?

You should **never** change a tag. Ever.

> Seems terrible for maintenance.

Exactly.

> Considering it is automatically assigned, it should be done only once and cached.

It is, at runtime.

> Even better, it should be done in compile time.

Well, I'm not focusing on the "infer" aspects, but *in general* that is an ongoing discussion I'm having with the compiler team.

> Am I missing something?

I think so, yes; in particular, you **should not be using** "infer by name" options on models that are *ever* going to change. That option was added as a pragmatic way to *just make things work* on existing fixed models, but it is *very* brittle - and in many ways dangerous. There *should* be warnings that appear in your intellisense about this, but frankly the *recommended* option is: always be explicit. Add `[ProtoMember(42)]` (or whatever) to each property. Then there's no guessing, and no risk of adding new members that break things. You can see everything, and you can understand everything.

Comment: Well, this answer my question and I'll accept it and I even agree with you, but it's sad that it would take too much effort to try to migrate apparently for few things missing when considering a large solution. :( So possibly I'll need to step back and give up migrating as it would take too much time. I'll check if it's worth it, Thanks btw.