# Injecting Services In Deserialized Data Contract Proxies

Tags: wcf, autofac

I'm using Autofac with WCF integration in a project. I'm trying to figure out a way to lazy initialize data contract proxy collection properties to avoid transferring entire object graphs across the wire.

My current plan is to inject the WCF service in each deserialized data contract so they call the service, get the collection property data and initializes it.

My question is: Is there a way to tell Autofac to inject services in each data contract proxy deserialized at the client? Like some tweaking at the `DataContractSerializer` or something.

(No service locator, please...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing like this available "out of the box" with Autofac. There is something similar in Autofac's MVC integration, but that's because MVC has a more specific integration point for that sort of thing (`IActionInvoker`).

You might be able to write a custom client-side behavior that intercepts certain known types (like collections) on the client and swaps in a lazy-initialized collection. [There's a similar question here asking about how to swap the `DataContractSerializer` out at runtime.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971743/custom-wcf-datacontractserializer) You could use a mechanism like that.