# DisplayAttribute name property not working in Silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I am binding `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property to the `List<PersonDetails>` object. I am getting datas through ***Silverlight-enabled WCF Service***. So the `PersonDetails` class is implemented in Web Project. Each DataGrid's header text is changing as i want if the class is located in Silverlight project. But then I can not use this class in the web service. *The only solution is to add same class in to the both of the projects.* But, is there any other way?

The class looks like that:

```
[DataContract]
public class PersonGeneralDetails
{
    // Properties

    [DataMember]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Sira")]
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Seriyasi")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

It seems attributes aren't generated in web project. I know that I can change header text using DataGrid events. But i want to make it work using attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *problem* is the WCF `DataContract` is an inter-operable mechanism that can be used across languages and platforms.

If you take a look to serialized data generated by the `DataContractSerializer` (or its code in `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`, specifically `InternalWriteObjectXyz()` methods) you'll see that it merely serializes values into a simple XML message. Nothing related to .NET Framework will be there so all kind of attributes, both custom and compiler generated, will be stripped out and won't even received by the client.

It works creating a **copy of your data** and sending them from server to client, clients will then create a **new class with the same signature**. Note: a **NEW CLASS** with the same signature, **NOT JUST A NEW OBJECT** of the original class.

Of course there are some workaround for this. You may write **your own serializer** (see [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971743/custom-wcf-datacontractserializer) for an example) or your own `ISerializationSurrogate`.

If you can **deploy/share your assemblies** to your clients you have a nice workaround: just deploy them and `DataContractSerializer` will build the right object on your clients (exactly the same one you had on the server, with all its attributes). Just remember that:

- If custom attributes comes from run-time values (for example because of localization) then they'll be resolved on the client, not on the server (because attributes will be *created* on the client, their values won't be included in the XML message).
- In the client application you need to add a reference to the assembly that contains your types.
- When you add your service reference you have to instruct VS to use them (or it'll create proxies), in the **Service Reference Settings** dialog select **Reuse types in referenced assemblies** (you can limit this to only assemblies you want to share).

Comment: Also, I have one more question. I was studing about solutions that you have offered me. I came across Adding class as a link. Does it mean deploying/sharing assemblies?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev RIA Services? I don't know if they "keep" attributes or not, let me know if it works!

Comment: After click on "Add Existing Item" in Silverlight project, i choose the class in the web project. And there were two choice: To add the class and To add the class as a link.
No it is not RIA. It is Silverlight-enabled WCF service.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev you clone them. Then it's more "clean" to put everything you want to share in a shared assembly and to deploy it. In case you don't want to deploy logic you may need to move it to derived classes (in another, non deployed, assembly)