# exposing datacontract defined in a different namespace via WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have developed a webservice, it accepts object as input

```
namespace Someservice
{
    public bool CreateBehavior(ClassInput classInput) 
            {

                  // code here

            }
}
```

now I have defined this `ClassInput` as a `datacontract` in business entities which is a different namespace

```
namespace Someservice.BusinessEntities
{
    [DataContract]
        public class ClassInput
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int intvariable{ get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string stringVariable { get; set; }
        }
}
```

To use this ClassInput in the webservice i have added project reference to Business entities project.
Now how can i expose this datacontract to consumer of this webservice?
For instance in client side, they will need this classInput, but its not exported via service!!

`SomeserviceClient someserviceClient = new SomeserviceClient();
 someserviceClient.CreateBehavior(`**`classInput`**`)`

I read about datacontractsurrogate but i am not able to map that to this scenario

Comment: Unless you have some [special requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292947/displayattribute-name-property-not-working-in-silverlight/15293784#15293784) a web service consumer won't need your original assemblies. Just publish your web-service and you're done.

Comment: but in client how can we create the object `classInput` ?

Comment: You don't do directly. VS will generate classes for that from WSDL. See link in my comment.