# C# XmlSerializer Order decorator issue with inherited class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

This code is not giving the proposed result, as the order of the elements does not appear as specified:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlSerializeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            SubClass test = new SubClass();
            test.A = "A";
            test.B = "B";
            test.C = "C";

            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SubClass));
            TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml");
            SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, test);
            WriteFileStream.Close();
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class BaseClass {
        [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
        public string B { get; set; }
    } 

    [Serializable()]
    public class SubClass : BaseClass {
        [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
        public string A { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
        public string C { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

It gives this result:

```
<BaseClass>
  <B>B</B>
  <A>A</A>
  <C>C</C>
</BaseClass>
```

What could be done to get the correct order (A,B,C)?

I have tried these alternatives as well:

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseClass), new [] {typeof(SubClass)});
new XmlSerializer(typeof(SubClass), new [] {typeof(BaseClass)});
```

Answer (score 6):

The default .NET [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) serializes data members in the following order:

- Base Class hierarchy (top-to-bottom, ie. your class instance in the end)
- Data members without Order attribute alphabetically
- Data members with Order attribute (members with the same order produces alphabetical order)

Please see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

If you want different behavior you have to implement your own data serializer inheriting from [XmlObjectSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.xmlobjectserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). - Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971743/custom-wcf-datacontractserializer).

**Edit/Note:**
XmlSerializer and DataContractSerializer use similar ordering. Unless you need full control of your xml format, I would go with DataContractSerializer instead. Please see this [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20130430190551/http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use abstract properties, and attach the [XmlElement] attributes to the bottom level.  So if B were abstract in BaseClass, then you could override it in SubClass with the [XmlElement] subclass.  The BaseClass version would need to have [XmlIgnore] on it to avoid duplication.  Then all the serializable properties would be in SubClass and they would sort properly.  (If you needed BaseClass to also be serializable, you might have to pull out a common superclass so that no serializable class has a serializable subclass.)