# Soap ui testing with mixed attribute order

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, soap, soapui

I have a WCF web service and testing with soap ui. When I create new request 
soap ui shows elements in alphabetical order and test result is succesfull.

```
   <v1:subscriberInput>
     <ipAddress>127.0.0.1</ipAddress>
     <operatorCode>3</operatorCode>
     <pageNo>1</pageNo>
     <password>passwordhere</password>     
     <username>userhere</username>
  </v1:subscriberInput>
```

If I mix some of element order manually as the below in SOAP-UI, some of the attributes 
not set in object. When I debug my code, I saw that **subscriberInput** object
has some null values or primitive types has default values.

```
 <v1:subscriberInput>
     <password>passwordhere</password>
     <ipAddress>127.0.0.1</ipAddress>         
     <pageNo>1</pageNo>             
     <username>userhere</username>
     <operatorCode>3</operatorCode>
  </v1:subscriberInput>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The default element order in WCF de-/serialization is alphabetical.

By default WCF uses [DataContractSerializator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which by default uses alpabetichal order of elements.

**Here are your options**:

- If you want to support a **specific order** of de-/serialized members you can use the [Order property of DataMember attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order.aspx).
- If you want to support **arbitrary order** or elements you can write your own Serializer which reorganizes elements and then internally calls DataContractSerializator. See a hint in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971743/custom-wcf-datacontractserializer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply  but my problem is about setting values to object

Comment: Elements that does not appear in the order expected by WCF will simply be discarded; meaning they will have their default value.

Comment: So can i add spesific order for solving problem?

Comment: Yes you can. I often do that to make sure that elements of special interest appear at the top of the request/response (e.g. a 'name' or 'id' element)

Comment: I specified order of elements so order changed in SOAP UI request. I added values in element tags it works but in the second request if I change order of any element it fails

Comment: This is expected behavior. You have to provide elements in the correct order. If you want to be able to submit elements in any order then you must implement your own serializer as described above.