# Remove namespace from generated XML in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XmlSerializer: remove unnecessary xsi and xsd namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760262/xmlserializer-remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces)

I'm generating some XML using XMLSerializer and a class marked up with attributes. This XML is sent to a REST web service.

It generates the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <first-name>API</first-name>
  <last-name>TestPersonDeleteMe</last-name>
  <title>Delete me</title>
</person>
```

All would be well, except the web service I'm using doesn't understand the schema stuff and throws a 500 error.

Is there a way to stop XmlSerializer adding `'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"'` to the *person* tag?

Comment: It's not my web service.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact it's broken. Do something about it.

Comment: Yeah i would try and report that as a bug, a webservice that takes xml input but canot deal with the xml namesapce attributes is broken.  Worst case is it should ignore them.

Comment: I've reported it, but would still like someone to answer my question. I can't wait for them to fix it.

Comment: @BenRobinson Yeah - people's webservices are broken. I've just come here because of the same problems parsing XML if it has a namespace. Ho-hum.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

if you use custom serializer try this

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
```

then add namespaces object to your serializer.