# removing namespace tag (xmlns:) from XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I want to generate following xml output in my C# code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CallConnectReq Xmlns="urn:interno-com:ns:a9c" reqId="9" msgNb="2">
  <LocalCallId>0</LocalCallId>
</CallConnectReq>
```

right now I am achieving this as follows:

```
var xnameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                xnameSpace.Add("Xmlns", Constants.XmlNameSpaceValue);
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objToSerialize.GetType());
                var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, objToSerialize, xnameSpace);
                return stringWriter.ToString().**Replace("xmlns:","");**
```

But I want to **remove "xmlns:"** tag without using Replace() method.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlSerializer: remove unnecessary xsi and xsd namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760262/xmlserializer-remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces)

Comment: @deathrace - what does the type look like, and what is the current xml looking like?

Comment: @jgauffin (my previous comment was incorrect, btw) - it is certainly *related*, but the syntax to get a default namespace is subtly different, and requires other changes to the type definition - sufficiently enough to be separate, IMO

Comment: @deathrace you really don't want `Xmlns="..."`, for the simple reason that that **isn't a valid namespace qualifier**; it **must** be `xmlns="..."`

Comment: actually I want to keep Xmlns="" as per my projects requirement.
but I dont want default xmlns:

Comment: If I remove .Replace() method, It gives:
<CallConnectReq xmlns:Xmlns="urn:intrado-com:ns:a9c" reqId="9" msgNb="2"/>

Comment: @deathrace.dj PLEASE double-check with whoever wrote the spec; `Xmlns` is **almost certainly** a typo in the spec, and has nothing to do with xml namespaces. The only way to add an `Xmlns` is via an `[XmlAttribute("Xmlns")] public string Foo {get;set;}` with value `"urn:blah"`, but note that it is **just** an arbitrary attribute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *genuinely* want `Xmlns` (which, to restate, I strongly believe is a typo of `xmlns`, and if not: is a bad choice in that it adds confusion), then:

```
var xnameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xnameSpace.Add("", "");
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (CallConnectRequest));
ser.Serialize(destination, new CallConnectRequest {
    RequestId = 9,
    MessageNumber = 2,
    LocalCallId = 0
}, xnameSpace);
```

using:

```
[XmlRoot("CallConnectReq")]
public class CallConnectRequest {
    [XmlAttribute("Xmlns"), Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string XmlNamespace {
        get { return "urn:interno-com:ns:a9c";} set { }
    }
    [XmlAttribute("reqId")]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("msbNb")]
    public int MessageNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LocalCallId")]
    public int LocalCallId { get; set; }
}
```

which writes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<CallConnectReq Xmlns="urn:interno-com:ns:a9c" reqId="9" msbNb="2">
  <LocalCallId>0</LocalCallId>
</CallConnectReq>
```

Answer (score 4):

To add *just* the default namespace:

```
var xnameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xnameSpace.Add("", "urn:interno-com:ns:a9c");
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (CallConnectRequest));
ser.Serialize(destination, new CallConnectRequest(), xnameSpace);
```

with:

```
[XmlRoot("CallConnectReq", Namespace = "urn:interno-com:ns:a9c")]
public class CallConnectRequest {}
```

Comment: still it gives following output : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> <CallConnectReq xmlns:Xmlns="urn:intrado-com:ns:a9c" reqId="9" msgNb="2" xmlns="xmlns=&quot;urn:intrado-com:ns:a9c&quot;"> <LocalCallId>0</LocalCallId> </CallConnectReq>
I want to remove 'xmlns:' from this.

Comment: @deathrace then you misapplied the change; you shouldn't have the `"Xmlns"` in `xnameSpace.Add`. It looks like you have: `xnameSpace.Add("Xmlns", "urn:blah")` - but that is **not** what I put in my answer

Comment: Ohh, my mistake. That worked fine. actually problem was I was using XmlType instead of XmlRoot. Thank you very much.

Comment: just one problem here again. its adding q1: at each node:
<q1:CallConnectReq xmlns="urn:intrado-com:ns:a9c" reqId="9" msgNb="2" xmlns:q1="xmlns=&quot;urn:intrado-com:ns:a9c&quot;"/>

Comment: @deathrace.dj you have extra quotes in your Namespace one... I'm guessing you have `XmlRoot(..., Namespace="xmlns=\"blah\"")` - again, please compare to what I have in the example; **just** the namespace

Comment: then how can I get this namespace : Xmlns="urn:interno-com:ns:a9c"

Comment: @deathrace.dj please, please take note: THAT IS NOT A NAMESPACE. It is just an attribute called `Xmlns` with value `urn:interno-com:ns:a9c`. Any similarity to namespaces is false. So; there are two options: a: you want a namespace, in which case it **must must must** be `xmlns` (and is handled by *this* answer), or b: you want an attribute - if so, see my *other* answer.