# How to append a new element to an existing XML file with namespace and xsi and xsi:schemalocation?

Tags: c#, xml

I know how I can create a new XML file, set the declaration, the name space and add new elements to the root. However, if I want to append elements to an existing file it is added xmlns as attribute of the new element:

```
<NewElement p3:id="1" idAux="A1" xmlns:p3="http://xyz.com/2006/bbb" xmlns="">
```

I try to use the loaded the namespace of the document, but that does not work.

How can I add new elements to an existing file and respect the format of the existing elements?

I am using linq to xml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```cs
// Assume 'el' is the new element that's created.
XElement el = new XElement("NewElement", new XAttribute("{p3}id", 1), new XAttribute("idAux", "A1"));
```

The above should create the following:

```xml
<NewElement p3:id="1" idAux="A1">
```

Note that the namespace `p3` may be created on the document root element--I'm not sure about that. Also I know that with the old System.Xml API, if you didn't specify a default namespace for your document, then the `XmlSerializer` would add the `xsi` and `xsd` namespaces automatically.

I know in the old Xml API, the correct way to specify a default namespace was to add a `XmlNamespaceManager`-type property to your class (which is a container for an array of `XmlQualifiedName` objects) and add a `XmlQualifiedName` object as follows: `new XmlQualifiedName(string.Empty, "urn:your-namespace-name")`. You probably need to do something similar for your document using XML-to-LINQ.

I have a SO post about that: [XmlSerializer: remove unnecessary xsi and xsd namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760262/xmlserializer-remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces/11138262#11138262,). HTH.