# C# remove attribute from root node

Tags: c#, xml

I tries to parse a XML file (get it from Dependacy Graph in VS 2012).

Here is sample of my .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DirectedGraph xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml">
    <Nodes>
        <Node Id="@101" Category="CodeSchema_ProjectItem" FilePath="$(ProgramFiles)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\unknwnbase.h" Label="unknwnbase.h" />
        <Node Id="@103" Category="CodeSchema_ProjectItem" FilePath="$(ProgramFiles)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h" Label="wtypesbase.h" />
```

in here, I needs to remove attribute "xmlns" from DirectedGraph.

here's my source to remove this

```
XmlNodeList rootNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("DirectedGraph");
foreach (XmlNode node in rootNode)
{
    node.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem("xmlns");
}
```

but this code doesn't work. If I don't delete this I can't select node like

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/DirectedGraph/Nodes/Node");
```

What should I do?

Comment: A well formed XML should have the xmlns attribute.

Comment: Is removing the namespace the actual requirement? Isn't your requirement simply to be able to parse the xml file? If I'm right, you have to deal with Xml namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like you can work *with* the namespace instead of removing the declaration:

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<DirectedGraph xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml"">
  <Nodes>
      <Node Id=""@101"" Category=""CodeSchema_ProjectItem"" FilePath=""$(ProgramFiles)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\unknwnbase.h"" Label=""unknwnbase.h"" />
      <Node Id=""@103"" Category=""CodeSchema_ProjectItem"" FilePath=""$(ProgramFiles)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h"" Label=""wtypesbase.h"" />
  </Nodes>
</DirectedGraph>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml");

var nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/d:DirectedGraph/d:Nodes/d:Node", manager);
Console.WriteLine(nodes.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
private static XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement xmlDocument)
{
    if (!xmlDocument.HasElements)
    {
        XElement xElement = new XElement(xmlDocument.Name.LocalName);
        xElement.Value = xmlDocument.Value;
        foreach (XAttribute attribute in xmlDocument.Attributes())
            xElement.Add(attribute);
            return xElement;
     }
     return new XElement(xmlDocument.Name.LocalName, xmlDocument.Elements().Select(el => RemoveAllNamespaces(el)));
}
```

Taken from: [How to remove all namespaces from XML with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c).

You might also want to check out: [XmlSerializer: remove unnecessary xsi and xsd namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760262/xmlserializer-remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces).