# Remove unnecessary xsi and xsd namespaces from wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I have built a web services which is working well except that I am trying to remove the xsi and xsd namespaces.

I have seen a lot link showing that i have to use a custom serializer like this :

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
```

but i did not find a way to implement this in my code. here is my code :

```
[ServiceContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyUser
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "getUserInfo?token={userId}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public PersonnResponse ValidateToken(string userId)
    {
        var response = new PersonnResponse();
        response.userId = userId;
        response.firstName = myOtherServiceGetFirstName(userId);
        response.lastName = myOtherServiceGetLastName(userId);
        return response;
    }

[DataContract(Name = "person", Namespace = "")]
public class PersonnResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "userId", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string userId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "firstName", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "lastName", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of these namespaces?

Comment: guess what? the client which is from an another company doesn’t like them!

Comment: "Doesn't like them"? You may want to gently ask the client the same question. Of course, you'll have to do it  in "client speak". For instance, say to the client, "we will be working to get rid of the namespaces since you find them untidy". The client then gets to say, "oh, yes, that's right", or "No, that's not the reason - we have this script that can't parse namespaces".

Answer (score 1):

To get what you're looking for you should implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[DataContract(Name = "person", Namespace = "")]
public class PersonnResponse:IXmlSerializable
{
   ...

     public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }


    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        var xd = XDocument.Load(reader);
        firstName = xd.Descendants().First (x => x.Name.LocalName == "firstName" ).Value;
        lastName = xd.Descendants().First (x => x.Name.LocalName == "lastName" ).Value;
        userId = xd.Descendants().First (x => x.Name.LocalName == "userId" ).Value;
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer){


        writer.WriteElementString("userId", userId);
        writer.WriteElementString("firstName", firstName);
        writer.WriteElementString("lastName", lastName);

    }
}
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.Serialize();
    }

    private void Serialize()
    {
        // Create an instance of the class, and an 
        // instance of the XmlSerializer to serialize it.
        var pers = new PersonnResponse(){ firstName="Call Me", lastName="Heisenberg", userId="Id"};
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonnResponse));

        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        ser.Serialize(tw,pers);
        Console.WriteLine(tw.ToString());

        //Deserialize from XML string
        var sw = new StringReader(tw.ToString());
        var NewPerson = ser.Deserialize(sw);

    }
}
```

You'll end up with XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<PersonnResponse>
  <userId>Id</userId>
  <firstName>Call Me</firstName>
  <lastName>Heisenberg</lastName>
</PersonnResponse>
```

Comment: I can understood the point. I want to know where exactly do I tell my WCF project that serializes this document and sends it back.