# Predefine XML namespaces for DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces, datacontractserializer

I'm building a self hosted WCF service. I'm building a special data structure for a very flexible transport of data. So far I test if my structure is serializable using the DataContractSerializer. That works fine and I'm happy about that, but there is something annoying me:

In my XML output are dozens redefined xmlns attributes e.g.:

```
xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

This should be better defined once in the root element so that bytes could be simply optimized. Is there a way to add custom namespace informations to the root element?

Here is a bigger example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
<DataObject xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test"
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Data xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
      <a:Key>ID</a:Key>
      <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1</a:Value>
    </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
      <a:Key>Value</a:Key>
      <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">42</a:Value>
    </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
  </Data>
  <Data xmlns:a="...">...</Data>
  <Data xmlns:a="...">...</Data>
  <Data xmlns:a="...">...</Data>
</DataObject>
```

What I want is something like this:

```
<DataObject xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test"
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
            xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Data>
    <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
      <a:Key>ID</a:Key>
      <a:Value i:type="b:int">1</a:Value>
    </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
      <a:Key>Value</a:Key>
      <a:Value i:type="b:int">42</a:Value>
    </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
  </Data>
  <Data>...</Data>
  <Data>...</Data>
  <Data>...</Data>
</DataObject>
```

Comment: [How to serialize an object to XML without getting xmlns=“…”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258960/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-without-getting-xmlns) <-- This contains what you want

Comment: @MarkusJarderot no not really. That seems to be a way to get rid of the namespaces in generall. WCF contracts needs that (so far I know)! I just want to avoid that there are severial redefinitions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
static void Main()
{
    var o = new Foo {
        Prop = new Dictionary<string,string> { {"foo","bar"} }
    };

    var ms = new MemoryStream();

    var slz = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    slz.WriteObject(ms, o,
        new Dictionary<string,string>
        {
            { "arr", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" },
        });

    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void WriteObject(
        this DataContractSerializer serializer,
        Stream stream, object data,
        Dictionary<string,string> namespaces)
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
        {
            serializer.WriteStartObject(writer, data);
            foreach (var pair in namespaces)
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", pair.Key, null, pair.Value);
            }
            serializer.WriteObjectContent(writer, data);
            serializer.WriteEndObject(writer);
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string,string> Prop;
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
     xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <Prop>
        <arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <arr:Key>foo</arr:Key>
            <arr:Value>bar</arr:Value>
        </arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    </Prop>
</Foo>
```

Comment: That looks perfect. Just a pity that there is not attribute which adds that declatation for me.

Comment: That seems to be a suitable solution. Thank you again! With the `DataContractSerializer` works everything fine. But the `DataContractJsonSerializer` throws a SerializationException talking about a `DataContractResolver` or that I should use the `KnownTypeAttribute`. Why does the `DataContractJsonSerializer` want that but the `DataContractSerializer` not?

Comment: The extension method in `Extensions` is only usable for the `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: I know that. I was just testing if my structure can be also serialited in the JSON format. (Without using your code)

Comment: You could add a dummy extension method into `Extensions` for `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully used the solution described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/07/24/optimizing-away-repeat-xml-namespace-declarations-with-datacontractserializer.aspx

You basically create a behavior which adds the namespaces to the root element for you.

From the article:

> Just create a serializer that inherits from XmlObjectSerializer that uses a DataContractSerializer for all of its methods, except for the fact that it registers additional namespaces at the top level. Then create a behavior that derives from `DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior` with a `CreateSerializer` method that returns the `XmlObjectSerializer` you just created and plug in the behavior.

In case you want to do it in Silverlight, you can also use the solution described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/24/wcf-extensibility-custom-serialization-in-silverlight.aspx