# Remove <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have googled a lot but I cant Found any solution :

```
  public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

        public WebService () {

            //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
            //InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

        public  string GetStudentInfo(int SerialNo)
        {
            Student obj = new Student();
            if (SerialNo is int)
            {

                int Serial = SerialNo;
                Student Stu;
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Courserecord where SNO='" + Serial + "'", con);
                var dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Stu = new Student
                              {
                                  SerialNo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SNO"]),
                                  StudentName = dr["StudentName"].ToString(),
                                  Gender = dr["gender"].ToString(),
                                  CollegeName = dr["CollegeName"].ToString(),
                                  FathersName = dr["FatherName"].ToString(),
                                  MotherName = dr["MotherName"].ToString(),
                                  Address = dr["Address"].ToString(),
                                  City = dr["City"].ToString(),
                                  State = dr["State"].ToString(),
                                  ContactNo = dr["ContactNO"].ToString(),
                                  EmailId = dr["Emailid"].ToString(),
                                  //
                                  Course = dr["Course"].ToString(),
                                  DateFrom = dr["DateFrom"].ToString(),
                                  DateTo = dr["DateTo"].ToString(),
                                  Department = dr["Department"].ToString(),
                              };

                    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Stu).ToString();
                }
            }
```

while getting response I am getting `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">` tag. How can we remove this please help.

Comment: *Why* do you need it removed?

Comment: @BerndLinde I dont want to need any tag with json

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258960/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-without-getting-xmlns

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
_doc.LoadXml(_data);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JObject.Parse(_doc.InnerText));
```

Comment: Would you care to add a marginal description rather than posting raw code?