# How to remove the header from an XML document

Tags: c#, xml, reference, header, tags

I'm not exactly sure if it's called a header, but anyway, I'm using a serializer in C# to generate XML tags,

How do I remove the xml link that's stuck on my first tag, for example currently I have:

```
<FirstTag xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> testData

</FirstTag>
```

And this is the desired output:

```
<FirstTag> testData </FirstTag>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know how to read an XML document into your program?  You need to remove what I believe are called attributes.  Basically, this is not a very well formed question.  You need to find a tutorial on parsing XML.

Comment: xmlns stands for xml namespace.  They are a type of attribute.  You don't need to remove the namesapaces to parse the document.  Why do you want to remove?.

Comment: What serializer are you using?  `XmlSerializer`?  `DataContractSerializer`?  Or something else?  How are you calling it currently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize an object to XML without getting xmlns="..."?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258960/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-without-getting-xmlns)