# Omitting xsi and xid namespaces while serializing an object in .Net using data attributes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have already visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258960/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-without-getting-xmlns) post but it is not helpful as I do not have control over serialization.

**Background:** I have a WSDL document which I have added as a web reference and got a reference.cs class. I am calling a service from .Net application but it is throwing an error while deserializing. Following are my XML files one which works fine and other which is giving me an error.

**Works fine:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:mas="http://orgname.com/compxref/Sometype">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <mas:SomeInputType> 
    ...............
```

**Throwing Error:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <SomeInputType
            xmlns="http://orgname.com/compxref/Sometype">
    .........................
```

My serialization class looks like below:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://orgname.com/compxref/Sometype")]

public partial class SomeInputType
{
    ...All the properties
}
```

Question: I want to change this XML to look like the one which is working fine. But here, I do not have control on serialization or deserialization. All I can do is to decorate Class and properties using data attributes.

Comment: What error is it throwing? Additional namespace alias declarations *should* be irrelevant, and the final namespace of `SomeInputType` should be the same either way (although the inheritance of child elements may behave differently, but you haven't shown them)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Sorry I do not have the exact error message but it is something like "Error parsing XML: mismatched tag." or "Error parsing XML: mismatched element." The only difference in both the XML are in namespaces, apart from it, they are identical hence I I am assuming these namespaces are creating a problem somewhere.

Comment: the exact error message would be useful, because the two `SomeInputType` elements shown *are actually identical* - even if they are using different ways of expressing the namespace. My suspicion is that something *under* `SomeInputType` is in a different namespace, probably because of the different inheritance rules between alias-prefix vs `xmlns="..."`. Likewise, the `soapenv:Envelope` and `soap:Envelope` are actually identical

Comment: Ok, I will ask for the exact error message and will update the question once I have it. Meanwhile, if you know any way to stop the addition of these namespaces in XML serialization?

Comment: if you don't control the serialization, you can't control the aliases, but: I don't think that's the problem - they are at worst redundant; unnecessary aliases won't impact any compliant parser